# Calling observable function in same class in angular2

Tags: angularjs, angular, rxjs

I have two function in a class where

First function returns Observable.

Second function is called from other component

I want call first function in second use the value of first and process it.

Sample code:

```
@Injectable()
export class SampleService {

service:string;

getService(): Observable<any> {
        return this._http.get(`url`, {
            headers: this.headers()
        }).map(res=>res.json();)
            .catch(err=>console.log(err);
    }
 }


generateToken():string{
const service="";
this.getService().subscribe(res=>{service=res});
//process it
return service;
}
```

Whenever i call the second function the value of service is return as empty.How to await till the subscribe is over and then process.

Comment: It's not clear to me what `2)` mean exactly.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer edited I need to observable value in second function

Comment: What is "second function"?

Comment: first function=>getService() second function =>generateToken() @GünterZöchbauer

Comment: You can't return a value that you get from an observable

Comment: I'm not returning the value.I'm trying to assign in local variable 'service'.@GünterZöchbauer

Comment: That's basically the same `return service` is executed before `service = res`. Async calls always need to be properly chained, otherwise it's not ensured the value was already received.

Comment: Ya I know but how to do that @GünterZöchbauer

Answer (score 1):

You can't return a value that you get from an observable.

You can either use `map` in the 2nd method as in the first method and then subscribe where you call `generateToken`

```
generateToken():string{
  return this.getService().map(res=>{return service=res});
}

someMethod() {
  this.generateToken.subscribe(res => this.service = res);
}
```

or assign it to a field in the 2nd property

```
generateToken():string{
  return this.getService().subscribe(res=>{this.service =res});
}
```

**update**

```
someMethod() {
  this.generateToken.subscribe(res => {
    this.service = res;
    // other code here
  });
}
```

Comment: I want to use the value not to return in generateToken()

Comment: Then you need to add the code that uses the value inside `subscribe(...)`

Answer (score 0):

This will return asynchronously because the subscribe will not come back until it receives a response:

```
generateToken():string{
    const service="";

    this.getService().subscribe(res=>{service=res}); //Async

    return service; //Instant return of blank value
}
```

I would suggest returning the observable itself and subscribing to it where you need it:

```
generateToken(){
    return this.getService().map(res => res.json()); //presuming json payload
}
```

Then inside your components after requesting sampleService in constructor:

```
this.sampleService.generateToken().subscribe(data = > { //use data });
```

Comment: I want use generateToken more than one call.

Comment: You can still use this in more than one call... any component can subscribe to this.